# gravity="fill_vertical" vs. layout_height="fill_parent" in Android

Tags: android, user-interface

Why does `gravity` offer a "fill_vertical" option? How is this any different from setting `layout_height` "fill_parent"? What if I choose a fixed `layout_height` and "fill_vertical" for gravity? Won't this contradict?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that using `gravity="fill_vertical"` indicates that the View should take up as much space as possible vertically while still respecting other Views' height constraints.  If you use `layout_height="fill_parent"`, you're telling the View to take up the entire parent's height; this may result in a single View pushing other Views off the viewport.